# go runtime fails to compile

Tags: go, cgo

I am just wondering why would go runtime fail to build. How do we pass flags (-fpermissive in this case) to the c compiler which golang  compiler is using to build the runtime. I am using gcc-4.6.2 on ubuntu 12.04

```
../../../thirdparty/go1.4.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_linux_amd64.c: In function ‘void _cgo_sys_thread_start(ThreadStart*)’:
../../../thirdparty/go1.4.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_linux_amd64.c:45:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘__sigset_t*’ [-fpermissive]
```

A sample program written also fails to compile, it seems the  nil defined in the go code is the problem, i wonder how others are working, when does the golang compiler compiles this  runtime code ?

```
gcc t.c -lpthread   -o t 
t.c: In function ‘void* hello_world(void*)’:
t.c:12:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘__sigset_t*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigthread.h:31:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_sigmask(int, const __sigset_t*, __sigset_t*)’ [-fpermissive]
rk@rk-VirtualBox:~$ gcc -fpermissive t.c -lpthread   -o t 
t.c: In function ‘void* hello_world(void*)’:
t.c:12:41: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘__sigset_t*’ [-fpermissive]
rk@rk-VirtualBox:~$ cat  t.c

#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

#define nil ((void*)0)
static void*
hello_world(void  *vptr)
{
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nil);
    printf("hello world");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int  ac, char **av)
{
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, hello_world, NULL);
    pthread_join(t, NULL);
    return 0;
}


    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigthread.h:31:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_sigmask(int, const __sigset_t*, __sigset_t*)’ [-fpermissive]
    make: *** [rulemanager] Error 2
```

Comment: That error would make sense if the C++ frontend was being used to compile the code.  Can you think of anything in your environment that could cause gcc to try and compile C code as C++?

Comment: In the sample program i added t.c you can see gcc fails  to compile the program with the code fragment taken from the  go runtime.c

Comment: I've tried your code on gcc 4.9 and it works just fine. I couldn't find any info on the minimal gcc version required to compile go 1.4, though.

Comment: Also tried your source on ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3 and it works as well.

Comment: Your test program compiles fine for me too.  However, if I force use of the C++ frontend with `gcc -x c++ t.c -pthread -o t`, I get the same errors you see.  If you can compile the program on your system with `gcc -x c`, then it is definitely a problem with the compiler's language selection.  C++ will be selected for files with the `.C` extension (upper case), so is there anything non-standard about the file system your code is on?